# Is there an IV perfection 'average'? How do you know if your Pokemon is above average?

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokemon GO's individual values (IVs), and some techniques for making the most of them, are well described in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/278111/141706) and [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/280537/141706).

I was wondering whether there is a generic 'average' IV perfection level (in % terms) that has been discovered or observed, and perhaps what the chance is of catching/hatching a Pokemon with a very high IV level?

The reason I ask is to try to determine whether I should focus on powering up, say, a 75% perfect Pokemon, or hold out until I get a 90%. Or keep holding out till I get a 99%, etc. At some point you must bite the bullet, so I am trying to determine where that point might best be.

Comment: my guess is that it is a bell curve with 50% being the average. so perfect and terrible are rare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of, but at the moment it's due to a bug. Currently, a wild caught Pokemon's # [correlates](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4v0puc/theory_potential_bug_with_ivs/) with their Attack IV. So a low # Pokemon will have a low Attack IV. This means that wild caught Pokemon's IV distribution is warped from what you'd reasonably expect, so don't hold out for a wild caught Perfect Bulbasaur (but do wait for a Perfect Eevee, as that's feasible). Until this bug is fixed, to get unbiased data we'd need to hatch a ton of eggs or capture a ton of Pokemon from nests, as those sources do not show this bug.

### Update

The bug appears to [be fixed](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/541esd/psa_scaling_bug_is_fixed/) as of today. Now we can gather some data and crunch some numbers.

### Updated Update

Looks like the [average is 7.5](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/54542l/proof_of_the_individual_attack_bug_being_fixed/), just like you'd expect.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that as @dragonrage said in a comment on this question, once this bug is fixed, the IV spread will represent a standard bell curve. That's how it is in the main games, at least, I believe.

Comment: Interesting insight, thank you! That explains why some have been finding perfect Magikarp.

Comment: Well, that explains why I have 20something Eevee and Eeveelutions with a 15 for attack.

Comment: Nice work! Thanks so much for coming back to update this.

Comment: @TimMalone I aim to please.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 IVs that range from 0 to 15 and they are (once the bugs are fixed) rolled for independently.

For Pokemon caught in the wild (i.e. ignoring starters, nest and egg hatches) the IVs are generated as simple random numbers, so any particular pokemon has a 1 in 16 chance of having any particular stamina, attack or defense IV.

However, because there are three IVs, the chances of getting above a particular combined perfection threshold combines multiplicativly: i.e. there are 16x16x16, or 4096 different possiblecombinations of IVs.

As a perfect (100% score) pokemon requires 3 separate rolls of 1 in 16: a perfect pokemon should occur in 1 in 4096 catches. A 97% pokemon requires two IV rolls of 1 in 16, and 1 roll of 2 in 16 - i.e there are 3 combos (15,15,14), (15,14,15) and (14,15,15), so the chance of getting a 97% or better pokemon is (3+1) in 4096.

A 95% pokemon adds an additional 6 combos (i.e. pokemon who's IVs are (14,14,15)* or (13,15,15)*), so the chance there is 6+3+1 or 10 in 4096.

And yes, this will look like a bell curve when plotted.

Comment: I am quite the lucky trainer. Caught a solid oddish on thursday. Perfect 0 0 0 IVs :D